# Redux toolkit in next js 14 using App routing in server components

Tags: next.js, react-redux, server-side-rendering, redux-toolkit, app-router

How to create redux store in next js 14 app routing server components, so that it works for SSR as well.

I checked for documentation, but it said that we need to change the component to client components, but that wont work for the ssr

Comment: Client Components SSR as well. You probably confuse SSR and RSC.